# How can I show and hide a single image in a Mac app?

Tags: macos, cocoa

What is the best control to use in a Mac OS app to handle showing a single image?  I need to be able to show and hide it programmatically, too.

Answer (score 4):

`NSImageView`. It has a `setHidden:` method, which you can use to hide it if needed.

Comment: More precisely, [all views have a `setHidden:` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/setHidden:), and NSImageViews are no exception.

Answer (score 0):

You should refer [Image Views guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ImageView/ImageView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000072i) and [NSImageView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).